# Testcafe .parent() of Selector sporadically fails before timeout

Tags: testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a TestCafe test that checks if a Selector's parent exists and somehow it fails every other time. Here's the relevant code:

```js
logWithTimestamp("Starts...");  // Prints "[2020-12-23T12:02:04.476Z] Starts..."
let state = await Selector('#indberetningsflow-knap-trin-stamdata', {timeout: 30000}).parent().exists;
logWithTimestamp(`State: ${state}`);  // Prints "[2020-12-23T12:02:04.618Z] State: false"
await t.expect(state).ok()  // Sometimes fails
```

As you can see, it fails after less than 200ms, even though the timeout is set explicitly to 30000. Now, I have an idea that maybe it fails when the selector is found, but the parent is not yet loaded. If this is true, why does TestCafe not wait for the parent to appear, and what can I do about it?

**EDIT**

I performed another experiment, and either there is something wrong with TestCafe or I have not understood something fundamental, but how can this fail after just 30ms?

```js
logMedTidsstempel("Starts...");  // Prints "[2020-12-23T12:42:15.041Z] Starts..."
let state = await Selector('#indberetningsflow-knap-trin-stamdata', {timeout: 30000}).exists;
logMedTidsstempel("Found child."); // Prints "[2020-12-23T12:42:15.072Z] Found child."
await t.expect(state).ok();  // <- fails :(
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your code example work, do the following:

1. Remove the `await` keyword from `Selector`
2. Remove the `timeout` option from `Selector` and pass it to the assertion method

```js
...
let state = Selector('#indberetningsflow-knap-trin-stamdata').exists;
await t.expect(state).ok({timeout: 30000});
...
```

You may also wish to refer to the following help topic: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements.html#selector-timeout

Comment: Thanks, missed that part! Could I do something like this 
`let s = Selector("abc");` and then `await t.expect(s.exists && s.hasClass("active")).ok();` ? Would it wait for both `exists`and `hasClass()` to be true?

Comment: The [`exists`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/exists) property and the [`hasClass`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/domnodestate.html#members-common-across-all-nodes) method return [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). When you use them with a `&&` operator, the returned Promise will be cast to a boolean value - `true`, so the `await t.expect(s.exists && s.hasClass("active")).ok();` assertion will always pass.

Comment: The following code should work:

`let s = Selector("abc"); await t.expect(s.exists).ok().expect(s.hasClass("active")).ok();`

Comment: Wow I did not know that! Thanks :)